# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Ipython'

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to parse the following line of code in an iPython notebook.

```
from Ipython.display import display, Image
```

I get the following error,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Ipython'
```

When I run `pip3 install Ipython`

Here's what I get.

```
Requirement already satisfied: Ipython in ./.envs/dl/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I'm running the code in the same virtual env in which ipython is installed. What am I missing. My python version is 3.6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its `from IPython.display import display, Image`

'P' also caps in IPython

Comment: Gosh how could I miss that. Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. You have to pay attention to which python version you are using, which pip version, and which environment too. I made a stupid mistake at first and installed TensorFlow on a virtualenv, then tried to call IPython which means my function and installation had different paths.
I recommend using "python -m pip install"